# What is the meaning of a folder whose name is user and IP address of the server I connect to?

Tags: ssh, directory

A folder was created on my computer and its name is user@xx.xx.xx.xx. That is a server I remotely connect. The folder has a lock symbol on it and it is write protected. What is it?

edit-
The contents of the folder are some of the things I **scp** to the server of that name.

Comment: What is the path to the folder?  Is that name copied literally or have you replaced an actual name and IP address?

Comment: The folder got created in the home directory. I replaced it with xx.xx..

Comment: Maybe at one point you might have accidentally typed in `cp` instead of `scp` and it created the folder.  Check your history by running `history | grep <ip address>` and see if maybe it was an accident.

Comment: Thanks @Terrence. But why is it write protected?

Comment: Probably created by running sudo at the first of the line.   If you do an `ls -al` on that folder you should see the permissions and who is the owner of it.

Comment: That was the case ! Successfully deleted it by sudo rm -r. Thanks a lot @Terrance

Comment: user239457 You might consider asking @terrance to write his resolution as an answer to your question.  This way you can accept the answer which will make it easy for others with a similar problem to find an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me often.  It's one of two things:

```
# Notice the missing ':' after host?
scp -r foo/ user@host

# in this case, with or without the ':', the `cp` is what's wrong.
cp -r foo/ user@host
cp -r foo/ user@host:
```

Usually, it's the first example that I mistype. I forgot the `:`, which scp treats as more or less a literal cp command.

For the second part of the mystery -- Since you also mentioned the folder is write protected, likely you included a `sudo` in front of one of these commands at one point.  Again, I've done the same thing many times.

**References**:

- See the discussion at this [q/a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28968/is-it-possible-to-make-scp-fail-when-you-do-a-local-copy) for more background.